# Eclipse stopped compiling after Mavericks

Tags: c++, eclipse, osx-mavericks

So I installed Mavericks and an **Eclipse C++ project** (my thesis code >_<) that previously worked well now gives me many errors.
It's about compilers and stuff, and I'm quite confused on what to do since my programming skills are limited to a physicist need (shame on me I know).
I'll post an image because there are several different errors.
[image: errors and warning that were not there before]

Hints?

Comment: (re)install the command line compiler using `xcode-select --install`? and get the CDT to rescan the compiler configuration

Comment: reinstalled CL several times already, how do I get the CDT to rescan the compilers?

Comment: One **major** hint: Don't update compilers, IDEs, LaTeX/TeXlive while writing your thesis...

Comment: yeah .. I knew it, in fact I didn't. I majored without any problems, but I had to retake the code to write a paper on it.. and BUM damn mavericks messed it up all x_x

Comment: Right click on the project, go to `Index` -> `Rebuild`. It seems to do the trick. The only issue is that you can't actually run the code in the debugger because lldb is not supported (or wasn't the last time I looked).

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. Still giving me the same errors.

Comment: I see you have a make file. Try running the make file on command line?

Comment: Based on the error 'use of undeclared identifier `sleep`' message, I'm going to go with add: `#include <unistd.h>` to that file. I have no idea what a `User` structure is, but you've probably got a `User[someVar]` declaration which won't work with clang++, convert the code to use a vector which could have the same effect, but is more compatible with the *newer* compiler

Comment: The problem is that the code is structured on many old fashioned arrays. It consists of >30 different files linked to each other in a way I don't even remember. I just can't redefine all the vectors. I built it like that because the compiler let me do that before today. Is there a way to use the old compiler?

Comment: It's a gcc-ism, you could try installing gcc using macports/brew and making that your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by downgrading Xcode to the previous version (4.6.3) instead of 5. 
Don't know why, but it worked.